# What is the best practice to manage user profile when using Huawei Auth Service

Tags: huawei-developers, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

When using Huawei AppGallery Connect Auth Service, I tried to get user profiles by using getPhone(), getEmail(), getDisplayName(), etc according to the reference from [Huawei Developer Site](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agconnectuser-0000001054522513). But for the most time, if not all the time, getEmail() returns a null. So does getPhone().

How do I suppose to manage the user profile if such info is always empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best practice would be to capture such info and mange it locally regardless what is available from `AGConnectAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(). getPhone()` would return a value when using Auth service by registering with phone number`. getEmail` would return a value when registering with email account. This is not ideal, but this is what has been designed.

Answer (score 0):

getEmail() and getPhone() are used to obtain information about the email address and the mobile number of **current signed-in user**. This parameter is returned when email or mobile number authentication of Auth Service is used by a user. Then you can manage the user profiles.

Comment: Could email and/or phone number be extracted and returned from authentication credentials if it is contained in such credentials?